# certs having Signed Certificate Timestamp not working with apache 2.2.15

Tags: apache

After updating the certificate which having "Signed Certificate Timestamp" apache 2.2.15 not picking those new certs ,Is there any way to make apache 2.2.15 to work with SCT certs

Comment: try `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: still not taking the new certs